# Powershell creating bulk users with a script

Tags: powershell

I need to create a lot of users so I wanted to use this script, I created it by myself. The script completed, but if I look in my ADUC there are no new users, what is wrong with my script?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ADusers = Import-csv C:\TEST\Create.CSV

Foreach ($user in $ADusers)
{

    $username   = $user.username
    $password   = $User.password
    $firstname  = $user.firstname
    $Lastname   = $user.lastname
    $OU         = $user.ou

    {
        New-ADUser
        -SamaccountName $username '
        -Name "$firstname $lastname" 
        -ChangePasswordatlogon $True '
        -Givenname $firstname '
        -Surename $lastname '
        -path $OU 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `New-ADUser` is running without any parameters.

When splitting a command over multiple lines, you need to use a backtick at the end of each line to signify the command continues on the next line.

If you don't do this, the preceding lines aren't linked to the line above.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ADusers = Import-csv C:\TEST\Create.CSV

Foreach ($user in $ADusers)
{
    $username   = $user.username
    $password   = $User.password
    $firstname  = $user.firstname
    $Lastname   = $user.lastname
    $OU         = $user.ou

    New-ADUser `
        -SamaccountName $username `
        -Name "$firstname $lastname" `
        -ChangePasswordatlogon $True `
        -Givenname $firstname `
        -Surename $lastname `
        -path $OU
}
```

Note: The indenting isn't required in PS, but makes it easier to read and understand the lines are linked to the Command above.

Comment: It's still not working... sorry i'm pretty new with powershell                           Foreach ($user in $ADusers)
{

    $username   = $user.username
    $password   = $User.password
    $firstname  = $user.firstname
    $Lastname   = $user.lastname
    $OU         = $user.ou

}
  
    
{ New-ADUser
-SamaccountName $username 
-Name "$firstname $lastname"
-ChangePasswordatlogon $True 
-Givenname $firstname 
-Surename $lastname 
-path $OU 
   }

Comment: @Remco, looks like you have placed brackets "{" to the wrong place. So you now have New-ADUser running out of the foreach loop.

Comment: Updated answer to make it clearer - you don't need the second set of `{ }`, the backticks are instead of these.